# how to use the API calls in bonjour mDNSPosix

Tags: bonjour, mdns, dns-sd

I have installed apple mDNSreponder on linux and able to publish the service via command line 
$ dns-sd -P Stack Overflow _ftp._tcp. .  80 AIR 14.99.8.77

Now I want to know how to use the API call of this in my app to publish the same service .
When I compiled the bonjour source code I got the  two libraries **libdns_sd.so  libnss_mdns-0.2.so**

Can anyone suggest me how to call apis using my linux c code ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Link `libdns_sd.so` to your project and include `dns_sd.h` too. Now follow `dns_sd.h` file to see various features like registering service, browsing, etc.